# I'm having an issue parsing a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a text file, and I want to load it into a dictionary in Python.

text looks like this, tab delimiated:

> Form   Dosage  ReferenceDrug   drugname    activeingred
>   INJECTABLE; INJECTION  20,000 UNITS/ML     LIQUAEMIN SODIUM    HEPARIN SODIUM
>   INJECTABLE; INJECTION  40,000 UNITS/ML     LIQUAEMIN SODIUM    HEPARIN SODIUM
>   INJECTABLE; INJECTION  5,000 UNITS/ML      LIQUAEMIN SODIUM    HEPARIN SODIUM

And right now my code looks like this, but it does not work (list index out of range, and nothing pushed to the dictionary).  I dont know where I'm going wrong, not a programmer.  Thanks for any help.

```
import sys

def load_medications(filename):
    meds_dict = {}
    f = open(filename)
    l = " "
    # print f.read()
    for line in f:
        fields = l.split("\t")
        ApplNo = fields[0]
        ProductNo = fields[1]
        Form = fields[2]
        Dosage = fields[3]
        ProductMktStatus = fields[4]
        TECode = fields[5]
        ReferenceDrug = fields[6]
            DrugName = fields[7]
        ActiveIngred = fields[8]

        meds = {
                "ApplNo": ApplNo,   
                "ProductNo": ProductNo, 
                "Form": Form,
                "Dosage": Dosage,   
                "ProductMktStatus": ProductMktStatus,
                "TECode": TECode,
                "ReferenceDrug": ReferenceDrug, 
                "DrugName": DrugName,
                "ActiveIngred": ActiveIngred
            }       
        meds_dict[DrugName] = meds
    f.close()
    return meds_dict


def main():
    x = load_medications("druglist.txt")
    print x



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: FYI, you can also write `ApplNo, ProductNo, […] = l.split('\t')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your field names are all valid Python identifiers, why not read your data into namedtuples instead of dicts?

```
data = """Form Dosage ReferenceDrug drugname activeingred INJECTABLE; INJECTION 20,000 UNITS/ML LIQUAEMIN   SODIUM HEPARIN  SODIUM  INJECTABLE; INJECTION   40,000 UNITS/ML LIQUAEMIN   SODIUM HEPARIN  SODIUM  INJECTABLE; INJECTION   5,000 UNITS/ML  LIQUAEMIN   SODIUM HEPARIN  SODIUM  INJECTABLE""".split('; ')

from collections import namedtuple

# define class DrugData as a namedtuple, using the headers from data[0]
DrugData = namedtuple("DrugData", data[0])

# use a list comprehension to create a DrugData for each data line
druglist = [DrugData(*line.split('\t')) for line in data[1:]]

# access each tuple in druglist, using attribute access to individual fields
for d in druglist:
    print "%s | %s | %s" % (d.ReferenceDrug, d.Form, d.Dosage)
```

Prints:

```
LIQUAEMIN | INJECTION | 20,000 UNITS/ML
LIQUAEMIN | INJECTION | 40,000 UNITS/ML
LIQUAEMIN | INJECTION | 5,000 UNITS/ML
```

EDIT:

Looking back at your original question, it looks like you want to create a single dict of all of these entries, keyed by `drugname`. Unfortunately, dict keys have to be unique, and in your example, all 3 entries have the same `drugname`. You may have to combine 2 or more fields to compose a truly unique key for a dict that handles all of these values, such as a tuple of `(drugname, Dosage)`.

OR, change your design slightly so that each `drugname` points to a *list* of matching values. The simplest would be to use a defaultdict instead of a dict, so that new entries are automatically initialized with an empty list. In your code, you would add an import statement:

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

and change the declaration of meds_dict to:

```
meds_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

meaning that any new keys that haven't been seen yet will be initialized using the function/class provided as the argument to defaultdict, in this case `list`.

Then to add new entries to meds_dict, instead of assigning with '=', you would append to the list of all matching meds/dosages:

```
meds_dict[DrugName].append(meds)
```

Now for any DrugName, you'll get the list of matching Form/Dosage/etc. records.

Answer (score 2):

Try `line.split` instead of `l.split`?

Answer (score 2):

You might have an easier time parsing this data with [the CSV module in the standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) - if you rig it up with tabs as your separator and `;` as your lineterminator, it should be have no problems parsing the file you posted.

Using a [DictReader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) would also make it a little easier to read over your rows (you could refer to things as `line['ApplNo']` instead of `line[0]`).

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the headers in your file map to what you want to call them in your code - so you would need to assign the names of the fields yourself based on what was in the dictionary.

Comment: This was going to be my answer too, but it looks like the file doesn't start with field names. Assigning the field names would be easy enough.

Comment: Oh, you're right - thanks for pointing that out. I'll update my answer.

Comment: When I was searching earlier, I saw a bunch of remarks on CSV.  It's more foreign to me, so I kinda wanted to just get this up and running in the simplest manner, but when I will look into it more.  It seems awfully applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) for this, assuming your file has a proper heading line at the beginning you should be able to create your dictionaries as simply as something like this:

```
def load_medications(filename):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open(filename), delimiter='\t')
    meds = {}
    for row in reader:
        meds[row['DrugName']] = row
    return meds
```

If your file does not have a heading line, you can pass in the field names to the `DictReader` initializer:

```
fields = ["ApplNo", "ProductNo", "Form", "Dosage", "ProductMktStatus"
          "TECode", "ReferenceDrug", "DrugName", "ActiveIngred"]
reader = csv.DictReader(open(filename), delimiter='\t', fieldnames=fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've overestimated the number of columns of your file. Where are `ApplNo`, `ProductNo`?

Answer (score 0):

You actually split `l`, and not `line`. You want:

```
def load_medications(filename):
    meds_dict = {}
    with open(filename) as f: # Ensure that the file gets closed
        for line in f:
            fields = line.split("\t") # line, not l
            keys = ["ApplNo", "ProductNo", "Form", "Dosage", "ProductMktStatus",
                    "TECode", "ReferenceDrug", "DrugName", "ActiveIngred",]

            if len(fields) != len(keys):
                raise ValueError("Malformed input line " + repr(line))

            meds = dict(zip(keys, fields))
            meds_dict[meds["DrugName"]] = meds
    return meds_dict
```

For details on why this works, read up on [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) and [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is assuming that there are 9 properties of a particular drug.  The sample text file you posted, however only has 5 properties.  When you call `fields = l.split("\t")`, an array of only 5 elements will be returned, because there are only 5 elements in the "druglist.txt". So if you index into `fields` with a value greater than or equal to 5, i.e. `fields[8]`, you will get an "index out of range" exception.